# How can I make sure that the text will not be written twice with the same value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Draws : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public string text;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private string oldText;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (lineRenderer == null)
        {
            lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

            lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.3f;
            lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.3f;
        }

        // 0,  0, 0
        // 5,  0, 0
        // 5, -5, 0
        // 0, -5, 0

        positions = new Vector3[5] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(5, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(5, -5, 0), new Vector3(0, -5, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0)};
        DrawLine(positions, Color.red, 0.2f);
    }

    void DrawLine(Vector3[] positions, Color color, float duration = 0.2f)
    {
        GameObject myLine = new GameObject();

        myLine.transform.position = positions[0];
        myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.positionCount = positions.Length;
        lr.startColor = color;
        lr.endColor = color;
        lr.startWidth = 0.1f;
        lr.endWidth = 0.1f;
        lr.useWorldSpace = false;
        lr.SetPositions(positions);
    }

    void DrawText()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (oldText != text)
            {
                var pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(positions[i]);
                text = positions[i].ToString();
                var textSize = GUI.skin.label.CalcSize(new GUIContent(text));
                GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
                GUI.Label(new Rect(pos.x, Screen.height - pos.y, textSize.x, textSize.y), text);
                GUI.contentColor = Color.green;
                GUI.Label(new Rect(pos.x, Screen.height - pos.y - 20, textSize.x, textSize.y), i.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (positions != null)
        {
            if (positions.Length > 0)
            {
                DrawText();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the method DrawText I'm using gui label to display a string on each two lines meeting corner position.
For example at 0,0,0

In the end when the square is closed the first position and the last one is 0,0,0 so I want to avoid displaying the same position text in red and green.

I added another Text variable called it oldText but not sure how to use it more.
I'm checking now if oldText != text but since oldText is all the time empty then it will be always true.

Example screenshot :

[image: Square with texts in red and green]

Comment: Hey Banzi, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using `List<Vector3>` can be helpful here. You can add all the vector3 that are already displayed and check when you start setting up another `GUI.Label()` you can check for the Vector3 which are already displayed.

Please take a look at the code. I'm adding all the reference that might be helpful at the bottom of the answer.

```
public Vector3[] positions;
public string text;
public List<Vector3> drawnPositions;

private void OnGUI()
{
    DrawText();
}

public void DrawText()
{
    //Clearing the list
    drawnPositions.Clear();

    //Your Text Drawing Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
    {
        //Condition to find that weather the Vector3 object is already drawn or not
        if (drawnPositions.FindIndex(x => x == positions[i]) < 0)
        {
            //If the condition is true and position is being displaied then add that Vector3 to list.
            drawnPositions.Add(positions[i]);

            //Your reguler code
            var pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(positions[i]);
            text = positions[i].ToString();
            var textSize = GUI.skin.label.CalcSize(new GUIContent(text));
            GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
            GUI.Label(new Rect(pos.x, Screen.height - pos.y, textSize.x, textSize.y), text);
            GUI.contentColor = Color.green;
            GUI.Label(new Rect(pos.x, Screen.height - pos.y - 20, textSize.x, textSize.y), i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**References**

[List.FindIndex()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=netcore-3.1)